# Why would my terminal freeze when globbing?

Tags: command-line, 16.04

I've been using Ubuntu Gnome `16.04` since April and this has been working completely fine until today. I'm not sure if it's related, but I'm using a Macbook Pro and after I booted it to Mac OS briefly today the wi-fi broke completely and I had to reinstall the drivers for it before I could use it again. Then I find that suddenly my terminal is messed up (and it definitely wasn't before this whole ordeal).

Essentially, any time I use globbing on the terminal it seems to more or less freeze that terminal tab. I can still type or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and get new lines, but nothing I type gets executed and nothing appears to be happening. Furthermore, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> do nothing apart from print `^C` etc. in the terminal.

In the case of simple globbing such as `ls ~/*`, the command works and then the terminal freezes (as though `ls` never returns). In the case of more complex ones like `ls ~/repositories/*/*` it freezes immediately, or at least it lists nothing at all (even though it should list plenty) before freezing.

I've tested this both in `gnome-terminal` and in `konsole`. It happens in both.

Edit: Several reboots later and suddenly it's back to working correctly. I swear, Ubuntu on a recent Macbook Pro is one of the most temperamental things I've ever used. :(

Comment: Can you [edit] you question to at least include a summary of the steps you took to reinstall the drivers? That might at least give us a clue.

Comment: @steeldriver All I did was select "Do not use this device" in "Additional Drivers", apply, then turn it back on. It did take ages though and didn't work when I didn't have an Internet connection.